# Hibernate and persistence. Annotate wrong

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I will try to tell you all my problem without showing to much code. I using DropWizard and i am trying to get a hang of how to use the hibernate with my mysql DB

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "mobile", nullable = false)
private String mobile;
```

In the example above i have a variable named id and the other mobile. Id is annotated with @Id. What i need to know is how to annotate mobile in the right way so i could use the function that works fine with id.

```
public Optional<Device> findById(Long id) {
    return Optional.fromNullable(get(id));
}
```

That is the function i use to find by ID. But i can't use a similar function for mobile. I will get a exception thrown telling me that a function excepts a long but gets a string. 
So my guess is that i annotated mobile wrong. But i don't have a clue over what i should try.

**Add some more information**

```
  public Optional<Device> findByMobile(String mobile) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(get(mobile));
    }
```

This is the function i want to work. But i get the following exception:

org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.mobiles.core.Device. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String

Comment: Your problem is because mobile is a String type and the method you want to use receive a long type, so you could change String for long to the mobile property or overload your method with String type

Comment: hmm to be more clear. Mobile has its own overloaded function that looks similar to findByID but takes a String. But i get an exception from that function because it tries to get the long variable and put it in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that the method get of hibernate receive the id of the entity ([see the api](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29)), in your case the id is long type, that is the reason the method throws the exception. So you can't use the method get with the mobile property

You can use hql or criteria to load the entities using the property mobile as filter.